# VBA Matrix multiplication MMult

Tags: vba, matrix

I’m struggling with “Run-time error ‘1004’: Unable to get the MMult property of the WorksheetFunction class”. I made the code as simple as possible but it still does not work.

I’d be grateful for a hint

```
Sub Matrix_Computation3()

Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ArrP As Variant
Dim ArrCW As Variant
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim Size

 Set ws3 = Sheets("STEP 3")

 Size = 6

 ReDim ArrP(1 To 1, 1 To Size)
 ReDim ArrCW(1 To Size, 1)

 ArrP(1, 1) = 0.2
 ArrP(1, 2) = 0.2
 ArrP(1, 3) = 0.2
 ArrP(1, 4) = 0.2
 ArrP(1, 5) = 0.2
 ArrP(1, 6) = 0.2

 ArrCW(1, 1) = 0.3
 ArrCW(2, 1) = 0.3
 ArrCW(3, 1) = 0.3
 ArrCW(4, 1) = 0.3
 ArrCW(5, 1) = 0.3
 ArrCW(6, 1) = 0.3

 Temp = ws3.Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(ArrP, ArrCW) ' here is an error
 MsgBox Temp(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `MMULT` the wrong kind of array. This is a worksheet function, not a VBA function.  The worksheet version of an array is a range of cells, so put the values into two worksheet ranges and refer to them there.

For example, part of your code might be:

```
Dim range1 as Range, range2 as Range
Set range1 = ws3.Range("A1:D1")
Set range2 = ws3.Range("E1:E4")
Temp = ws3.Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(range1, range2)
```

Also note that *the number of columns in array1 must be the same as the number of rows in array2*, and both arrays must contain only numbers.

Perhaps get the function working on the worksheet before trying to call it from VBA.

---

### More information:

- Office.com : [**`MMULT` function**](https://support.office.com/article/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb) (Excel)
- Office.com : [**`WorksheetFunction.MMult` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-mmult-method-excel) (VBA)

Comment: Both of my ranges are in two rows in the worksheet, thus I have to transpose one of them. I can loop through the range and store the data in a new range in the worksheet. Nevertheless it is not a gentle solution. I'd like to transpose the data in the back office (in the VBA). Do I have to go back to arrays for that reason or is there any other solution. If I have to use arrays, then I'm back on the beginning of my problem.

Comment: ok. I figured out hot to do it:
Temp=ws3.Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(range1, Application.Transpose(range2))